# Lubricating a mechanical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, maintenance, logitech-keyboard

My 1.5 year old son decided to test if my keyboard was compatible with the remains of a can of Red Bull, which obviously wasn't empty enough.

It only affected a few keys, so it was somewhat easy to clean up, using isopropyl alcohol under them, and made sure they were nice and clean.

Now that I've sorted out the sticky keys, I've noticed that they don't behave the same way they used to - There seems to be a lot more friction in them than before, and I'm thinking that I cleaned out some lubricant in the process or that the plastic isn't as smooth as it should be. Either way, I think lubrication should be an easy fix.

Which lubricant should I use on what seems to me as some PVC-like type of plastic? Preferably something dielectric, as I'm likely to use it other places too.

I tried [white lithium grease](http://www.logitech.com/nb-no/product/keyboard-k360), and while it helped some, it doesn't seem to be fit for the purpose, as it's not viscous enough.

Using a [logitech k360](http://www.logitech.com/nb-no/product/keyboard-k360).

Comment: The root problem is keyboard manufacturers rely on a perfectly smooth plastic surface to make a perfect keypress experience and no-binding. After 100 thousand uses, that surface gets skuffed. Any friction causes a rotational torque causing a jam, bind, squeak, or difficulty.  WD-40 and vasline and silicone makes things worse because either it quickly dries out and denatures the plastic, or the viscosity is too thin or too much and now you're back to square one.  Keyboard manufacturers have made sure keyboard lubrication requires a $150 investment plus hours of time to get right.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/313488/whats-the-best-lubricant-to-use-on-mechanical-keyboards) question seems to be almost exactly the same as yours. Basic run down of the advice given: graphite based lubricants (not recommended: RockPaperLizard pointed out graphite is electrically conductive and probably not well suited for this task) , an all synthetic lubricant like "Super Lube" (don't use anything petroleum based), and replacing the keys.

Comment: Graphite is electrically conductive due to an open covalent bonding site.  Although it might not hurt your keyboard, I wouldn't recommend graphite lubricants (especially in powder form) around microelectronics.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @MattWalck: Even though this question is closed I've edited your answer to remove the link to the SU rip-off site.

Comment: Appreciate that, good catch.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Someone has [reported](https://superuser.com/a/366557/741067) good results with graphite powder.

Comment: @jdk1.0 Thank you.  Do you know if graphite is conductive?